# Where would I find UI 'standards' for Windows applications

Tags: windows, hig

Where can I find standard guidelines for user interfaces of Windows applications? I have done a search with no luck, but there must be some sort of document on how actions should be handled.

Comment: Nobody really cares what you think of MYOB, this rant adds nothing to the question. You should have just stated that you were looking for the design guidelines for Windows apps, then you wouldn't be thought of as bitter and twisted :-) Saved from my usual "just close rants" behaviour because such a list _is_ actually useful to developers.

Comment: +1 But I am bitter and twisted

Comment: As am I, I just don't feel the need to let the whole world know. If/when I _break,_ then you'll know it, it'll be all over then news :-)

Comment: It was also a bit of a warning to people before they fall for the same trap and buy this rubbish.  But it's a moot point now thanks to some very skillful editing by Brad Larson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sigh...the usual thing.  After asking I found it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511440.aspx

Comment: The incredible thing about it is that these people spend a *lot* more time breaking the rules and making their software work differently than the user expects than if they'd just done what the platform does naturally.